# FusionPBX Public Context - Routing local extensions registered from Internet on port 5080

Tags: freeswitch

I am basically trying to call a local extension in a single domain - simbauc.com
Out of the box it works but that's only because endpoints will be on the LAN so they register on port 5060 and use the default context. But when any of my endpoints register from the outside they use port 5080 and that automatically puts them in public context.
What I need to be able to do is call local extensions for my endpoints that register from the Internet on port 5080. I can get this to work in regular FreeSWITCH but not in FusionPBX.

I get a no route error even after creating a dial plan in Dial Plan Manager.
Below is a sample of what i have configured:

```
<extension name="SIMBAUC.COM_Local_Extension">
 <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(10[01][0-9])$">
  <action application="log" data="CRIT SIMBAUC.COM Someone Dialed $1"/>
  <action application="export" data="dialed_extension=$1"/>
  <action application="bridge" data="user/${dialed_extension}@simbauc.com"/>
  <action application="answer"/>
  <action application="sleep" data="1000"/>
  <action application="bridge" data="loopback/app=voicemail:default 
  ${simbauc.com${dialed_extension}"/>
 </condition>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

The external profile is anonymous and doesn't actually handle registrations by default. You would either register to 5060 or you could copy the internal profile call it something like internal-5070 change the port to 5070 and set the dial_string in default settings to enabled. Hit reload on the default settings page and then run Advanced -> Upgrade -> App Defaults.